# Windows Service not launching as local session

Tags: c++, visual-c++, windows-services, createprocess

Am working on Creating windows service and launching an exe application through this,

from this link i have created a windows service [Windows Service](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/16488/A-Windows-Service-Application)

But when i create a setup and deployment and then if i install, the exe which am calling from the service is launched as LOCAL SERVICE.

Still i can the xxx.exe in task manager as LOCAL SERVICE.

I cant figure even with this help : [Launching GUI from windows service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/948417/how-to-launch-a-gui-program-in-a-windows-service)

How can i launch this exe as the local username which i have logged in ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a number of options for creating a process that runs under a different user from the parent process:

- [`CreateProcessAsUser`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/desktop/ms682429.aspx) or [`CreateProcessWithTokenW`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682434.aspx). These require you to obtain a primary token that represents a user, calling either `LogonUser` or `DuplicateTokenEx`.
- [`CreateProcessWithLogonW`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682431.aspx) which allows you to specify the user name and password as parameters.

However, if you want the process that you create to appear on the interactive desktop, you need to do quite a bit of work. This article covers the details: [Launching an interactive process from Windows Service in Windows Vista and later](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/winsdk/archive/2009/07/14/launching-an-interactive-process-from-windows-service-in-windows-vista-and-later.aspx).

Comment: Thanks a lot. Now i can deploy the exe with local session. But when i kill the exe from task manager, the service does not restarting the exe

Comment: That seems like a completely different question. Didn't I answer the question that you asked?

Comment: Definitely yes thats the answer am looking for